# R httr how to structure body

Tags: r, post, httr

I have a curl code below that runs in a terminal and I want to convert it httr code in R.

```
curl -X POST "https://api.purpleair.com/v1/groups/zzz/members" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-API-Key: xxxxxxxxx" -d '{"sensor_index":"yyyyyy"}'
```

This R code doesn't quite work.

```
library(httr)
url <- "https://api.purpleair.com/v1/groups/zzz/members"
body <- list(sensor_index = "yyyyyy") 
headers <- c("Content-Type" = "application/json",
             "X-API-Key" = "xxxxxxxxx")

response <- POST(url, body = body, add_headers(.headers = headers))
```

It returns

```
"error" : "MissingIdentifierError",
  "description" : "Missing sensor_id or sensor_index value."
```

I can't figure out how to turn `-d '{"sensor_index":"yyyyyy"}'` into a body.

Comment: Be sure to set `encode="json"` in the call to `POST`

Comment: make it an answer and I'll choose it. So simple and yet so unclear to the novice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass your `body=` as a list, by default `POST()` will use "multipart" encoding which more generally allows you to upload files and form data. But if you want `POST` to turn the list into a JSON string for you, you need to set `encode="json"`. When you use that value, it will also set the correct content-type for you so you don't need to explicitly set it in a header.